# Ruby on Rails 4 - CSV import - no implicit conversion into string

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm trying to import CSV data to my mysql DB but I'm running into an error when I try to upload the file :

```
no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String
```

This is what a line in the CSV file looks like :

```
751,"01/17/2015","11:17:32","60","TDFSRDSK","2","10","-1","0","3","","26","3","","","1","0"
```

here is the code for the import, in product.rb

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file) do |row|
    id, jour, heure, valeur, app, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l = row
    userid = current_user.id
    product = Product.create(date: jour, valeur: valeur,user_id: userid)
  end
end
```

in product_controller.rb

```
def import
 Product.import(params[:file])
 redirect_to_root_url, notice "Products imported"
end
```

in the index :

```
<%= form_tag import_products_path, multipart: true do %>
 <%= file_field_tag :file %>
 <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

and in routes.rb I have:

```
resources :products do
 collection {post :import}
end
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try give `params[:file].path` in argument. Like this,

```
Product.import(params[:file].path)
```

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620507/ruby-on-rails-csv-uploadimport-file-name-too-long?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Thanks I managed to get rid of the error messages with your solution, now it seems to work but no data are added to the SQL table

Comment: At creation, try by using `Product.create!(..)` . So it will trows exception if any.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my data mapping to the sql has a problem because they all show as NULL and none were created because I have a "validates" on the field in my model. I'll try to find the right way to map ip

Answer (score 3):

You need to do as :

```
CSV.foreach(file.path)
```

Your `file` is holding an instance of [`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) class. To know the path, use [`#path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html#method-i-path) method.